# Can I install Ubuntu on a Laptop?

Tags: system-installation

I have a completely blank, new out the box, hard drive. Can I still use Ubuntu 12.10 on my Laptop?

Comment: I cannot see why not? Are you experiencing problems?

Comment: Specifically, what kind of laptop?

Comment: To close voters: There's really no need to close this (except perhaps as a duplicate). Asking if Ubuntu needs any previous OS or data to install *is a perfectly good and well-formed question.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should be able to easily install Ubuntu onto it. Just get a flash drive or CD and put ubuntu ( which you can download here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and insert teh flash drive etc into your laptop and you should be able to downlod it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Ubuntu.

Ubuntu **does not need**:

- any operating system to already be installed
- any files or data already on the hard disk
- the hard disk to already be formatted

However, since your laptop doesn't currently have an operating system on it, you probably will not be able to use it to download Ubuntu and burn it to a CD/DVD (or write it to a USB flash drive). So you'll have to use another computer for this purpose.

Since you were able to post here on Ask Ubuntu, I am guessing you have access to another computer. Even if you cannot do that on the computer you're currently using (for example, if it's a library/cafe computer with very restrictive policies), most people have a friend, coworker, or other associate who can download Ubuntu and create installation media for them.

- [Download Ubuntu or your desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

However, if you prefer to purchase pre-created installation media, you can do that too. One way is [from Canonical](http://shop.canonical.com/). You can [get DVD's here](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17). Or [a pre-loaded USB flash drive here](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1043).

We have installation instructions you can use:

- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Or use the instructions on the Ubuntu website:

- [Install Ubuntu 12.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest)

*There's just one kind of Ubuntu installation that does require a pre-existing operating system installed. [A Wubi system](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) requires an existing Windows system. But a normal (non-Wubi) installation is better for most users, and certainly better for anyone who isn't running Windows too on the same computer.*